# Would puka work well with gevent or eventlet?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, gevent, eventlet

I was reading about the newer Python AMQP library Puka (not to be confused with Pika) and was wondering if the way it handles it's event loop would be compatible with gevent or eventlet. Based on my limited knowledge, it seems like you could automatically patch it with gevent/eventlet.

Thanks!

Source: http://github.com/majek/puka

Docs: http://majek.github.com/puka/puka.html

Comment: Have it worked? I'm just looking through puka code and I must admit I'm not convinced that puka is thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon initial inspection it appears to be pure Python so gevent and eventlet should work fine.

Comment: Both Eventlet and gevent support monkey patching `select` module which would be enough to make Puka's "simple interface" compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Puka doesn't do gevent/eventlet out of the box, but it shouldn't be hard to modify it.

Puka blocks only in one place (in the event loop), so replacing this part should be enough.